# Django/Local Library. How to assign current user to a field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've started learning Django and im doing a local library. I have a problem. I've created a model Book, which has a borrower. When I want to save current user as a borrower value changes only on page, but not in admin panel. It also changes every single book's value, not just the specific one.

```
class Book(models.Model):

      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      ISBN = models.CharField(max_length=13,unique=True)
      genre = models.ForeignKey(Gatunek,related_name='Books',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
      borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default='')

      def __str__(self):
            return self.nazwa


class BookRent(ListView):
     model = Book
     template_name = "Books/Book_rent.html"

     def get_queryset(self):
          user = self.request.user
          Book.borrower = user
```

Comment: `Book` is not a specific instance of the model, it is the model class itself, hence when you set `Book.borrower = user` you just set (and overwrite) the class attribute. Also you are trying to do this in a `ListView` which doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Did you register the model on the admin site? If you did not, try looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat so firstly i should change to UpdateView right?

Comment: @AaqibBashir I did, but thanks for a hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the fields of an object you need to use **UpdateView** instead of **ListView**.

```
class BookRent(UpdateView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "Books/update.html"
    fields = ["borrower"]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do it automatically, so that if I click on "Borror book" link, it would assign user to borrower without any interference

Comment: you need to get it in a View instead of UpdateView and update the fields you want then redirect to you ListView page, don't update your objects in list view its for showing them and pagination or something like this, if you want to update object in your list view create an update button for your list records.